# Legacy application failing to send trafic with Hl7 protocol to EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, ingress, eks

I am working on an application that consumes data sent over Hl7 protocol that has recently migrated to AWS, and that's where the issues started

The "Legacy application" requires a connection configuration that will specify to which ip/port dns/port it will send messages to

1. I tried setting up an ingress for a NLB that would route the traffic to the service
2. Our current workaround for this issue is an EC2 instance hosting the message receiving application, and the EC2 IP is used in the connection configuration
3. What works is when the Service is set to NodePort type, I am able to assign the Pods Ip:NodePort in connection assignment

What I'm looking for is to get rid of the EC2 and not not using the nodeport setting,
I tried configuring an ingress that I thought would work but when a messsage is being sent in return I get a 400 status

pre-migration we have self-hosted the application and just used the clusters ip:port but now it's not possible to do so